# Only one video card available on Dell Vostro 3550

Tags: 14.04, ati

I got used Dell Vostro 3550.
Specs says it have two graphic cards:

- AMD ATI Mobility Radeon HD 7450M/7650M
- Intel® HD Graphics 3000

But Ubuntu 14.04 LTS only see Intel (I tested 12.04 LTS and same results).
Preinstalled Win7 also saw only Intel before being erased.

What's going on? I suppose ATI card can't be unplugged.

Also in BIOS there is nothing about Video Cards.

Some testing:

```
filip@B17:~$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
filip@B17:~$
```

Comment: What is the name of your processor(s)

Comment: Vostro 3550 comes in 2 flavours: with an integrated graphics controller (Intel HD Series) **or** a discrete option (AMD Radeon). Please provide more details on the version (3550 is not the only set of numbers to identify it)

Comment: My processors: `cat /proc/cpuinfo` http://paste.rapidrage.org/CoECZfJdJovj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it, you do *NOT* have a AMD processor. The other type of Dell Vostro 3550 uses that processor, so it uses the "AMD ATI Mobility Radeon HD 7450M/7650M" card. AMD Processors use the "AMD ATI Mobility Radeon HD 7450M/7650M" card, and you have the Intel processor, which is not compatible and can't use the AMD card. The Intel® HD Graphics 3000 card is the one that you use, so there is no problem!

Cheers